# Angular 4 + ngBootstrap tooltip not presenting correctly

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am trying to create a simple ngBootstrap tooltip over a Fontawesome icon as follows:

```
<ng-template #tipContent>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
<i id="icon" class="fa fa-1x fa-info-circle" [ngClass]="icon" aria-hidden="true" placement="right" ngbTooltip="tipContent"></i>
```

I use the above Component as follows:

```
<app-tttest>Some tooltip text!</app-tttest>
```

While the tooltip does appear there are 2 problems:

1. The content of the tooltip says "tipContent".  I've done this exactly like the ngBootstrap docs but it doesn't work.
2. The tooltip is a rounded square, but there is not triangle pointing towards the element which popped it up.

The CSS I'm using is:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: 1. it should be [ngbTooltip]. 2. You're probably using an unsupported ng-bootstrap-bootstrapcss  version combination.

Comment: ok #1 you solved (the documentation is wrong on ngbootstrap site).  As for #2, I'm using the the css included with ngBootstrap...which seems to work on the documentation site

Comment: The documentation is not wrong at all. Which version of ng-bootstrap are you using, and which version of bootstrap are you using? Can you post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem?

Comment: I could swear the [] wasn't there - but when I search for it now I see it.  Unless some SO user suddenly changed it, I'll have to admin my mistake.  Still stuck with #2 however.

Comment: You don't answer the questions I ask, and you're not posting a complete minimal example, so...

Comment: @TSG can you add screenshot or create a plunker to reproduce?